# A little query, String in C

Tags: c, string, codeblocks

Recently I was programming in my Code Blocks and I did a little program only for hobby in C.

```
char littleString[1];

fflush( stdin );
scanf( "%s", littleString );
printf( "\n%s", littleString);
```

If I created a string of one character, why does the CodeBlocks allow me to save 13 characters?

Comment: Because C has a thing called ["undefined behaviour"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which means it's not necessary for compilers to error out when your program invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Calling `fflush` on an input stream is undefined behavior according to the specification. Some libraries allow it as an extension, but you should not do that.

Comment: Also, please make it a habit of writing a newline *after* the text you want to print. `stdout` (which is what e.g. `printf` writes to) is by default *line buffered* meaning a newline will flush the internal buffer and actually write the text to the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

C have no bounds-checking, writing out of bounds of arrays or dynamically allocated memory can't be checked by the compiler. Instead it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

To prevent buffer overflow with [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) you can tell it to only read a specific number of characters, and nothing more. So to tell it to read only one character you use the format `"%1s"`.

As a small side-note: Remember that strings in C have an extra character in them, the *terminator* (character `'\0'`). So if you have a string that should contain one character, the size actually needs to be *two* characters.

Comment: With respect to the last paragraph, this would be a newbie question, but '\0' are not 2 characters?. Equally, thank you for your comment, it served me much.

Comment: @NicolasMozo In string constants (also know as string literals) the sequence `"\y"` where `y` is a number is known as an octal escape sequence. It works just like e.g. `"\n"` does, but inserts the character whose encoding matches the octal number. In the case of `"\0"` it corresponds to the octal number `0` so the character corresponding to `0` is inserted into the string. And this is all done by the compiler, escape sequences are not parsed at run-time.

Comment: Really thanks you, you are a genius!! I think that the octals and hexadecimals numbers only served for CSS colors haha, now I nkow that I have much to learn about C. Equally thank you Joachim!

Answer (score 2):

LittleString is not a string. It is a char array of length one. In order for a char array to be a string, it must be null terminated with an `\0`.
 
You are writing past the memory you have allotted for littleString. This is undefined behavior.
Scanf just reads user input from the console and assigns it to the variable specified, in this case littleString. If you would like to control the length of user input which is assigned to the variable, I would suggest using scanf_s. Please note that scanf_s is not a C99 standard

Answer (score 0):

Many functions in C is implemented without any checks for correctness of use. In other words, it is the `callers` responsibility that the arguments fulfill some rules set by the function.

Example: For `strcpy` the Linux man page says

```
The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src, 
including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer 
pointed to by dest.  The strings may not overlap, and the 
destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.
```

If you as a `caller` break that contract by passing a too small buffer, you'll have undefined behavior and anything can happen.

The program may crash or even do exactly what you expected in 99 out of 100 times and do something strange in 1 out of 100 times.